# Unsure of how to implement an equation in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to implement the SummaRuNNer architecture ( Nallapati et al).

The equation I am stuck at in question is:
$$d = tanh(W_{d}\frac{1}{N_{d}}\sum_{j=1}^{N^{d}}[h^{f}_{j},h^{b}_{j}] + b)$$ 
Where,
$N_{d} = $ Num of sentences in the document, $h^{f}_{j}$ and $h^{b}_{j}$ are the forward and backward passes of the $j^{th}$ sentence, $[]$ is the concatenation operation, $b$ is a bias term and $W_{d}$ is a learnable parameter.

My question is, what is the best way to implement this in PyTorch.

Also, I am aware that there is already a version of this particular architecture implemented in PyTorch [here](https://github.com/hpzhao/SummaRuNNer/blob/master/models/CNN_RNN.py#L44), however, I am not sure if their implementation of this equation is quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this GitHub repo for implementing SummaRuNNer with Pytorch.

[The PyTorch Implementation Of SummaRuNNer](https://github.com/hpzhao/SummaRuNNer)